# How to delete the current node in a singly linked list?

Tags: java, singly-linked-list

I am trying to finish a program and I'm caught at a spot. My deleteCurrentNode method only partially works. For some reason when I try to traverse the linked list to find the currentNode it never finds it. Can someone provide me with a tip of how to get it to work?

The method itself checks 4 conditions:

1. If the list is empty.
2. If currentNode is null.
3. If the currentNode is the first node in the list.
4. If currentNode is somewhere in the list.

The other conditions work (to my knowledge). 4 is where the issue is.

```
public class LinkedList 
{
private Node currentNode;
private Node firstNode;
private int nodeCount;

public static void main(String[] args)
 {
 LinkedList test;
 String dataTest;
 test = new LinkedList();
 dataTest = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
 for(int i=0; i< dataTest.length(); i++) { test.insert(new String(new char[] { dataTest.charAt(i) }));  }
 System.out.println("[1] "+ test);

  for(int i=0; i< dataTest.length(); i++) { test.deleteCurrentNode(); }
  System.out.println("[2] "+test);

  for(int i=0; i< dataTest.length(); i++)
  {
  test.insertBeforeCurrentNode(new String(new char[] { dataTest.charAt(i) }));
   if(i%2 == 0) { test.first(); } else { test.last(); }
  }

  System.out.println("[3] "+test);

  for(int i=0; i< dataTest.length(); i++) { test.last(); test.deleteCurrentNode(); }
      System.out.println("[4] "+test);


      for(int i=0; i< dataTest.length(); i++) { test.insert(new String(new char[] { dataTest.charAt(i) })); test.last(); }
      System.out.println("[5] "+test);

    while(!test.isEmpty()) { test.deleteFirstNode(); }
    System.out.println("[6] "+test);

   for(int i=0; i< dataTest.length(); i++) { test.insert(new String(new char[] { dataTest.charAt(i) })); test.last(); }
  System.out.println("[7] "+test);

   while(!test.isEmpty()) { test.deleteFirstNode(false); }
   System.out.println("[8] "+test);

   for(int i=0; i< dataTest.length(); i++) { test.insertBeforeCurrentNode(new String(new char[] { dataTest.charAt(i) })); test.first(); }
   System.out.println("[9] "+test);
 }

public LinkedList()
{
    setListPtr(null);
    setCurrent(null);
    nodeCount = 0;
}

public boolean atEnd()
{
    //checkCurrent();
    return getCurrent().getNext() == null;      
}

public boolean isEmpty()
{
    return getListPtr() == null;
}

public void first()
{
    setCurrent(getListPtr());
}

public void next()
{
    checkCurrent();
    if (atEnd()) {throw new InvalidPositionInListException("You are at the end of the list. There is no next node. next().");}
    setCurrent(this.currentNode.getNext());
}

public void last()
{
    if (isEmpty()) {throw new ListEmptyException("The list is currently empty! last()");}

    while (!atEnd())
    {
        setCurrent(getCurrent().getNext());
    }

}

public Object getData()
{
    return getCurrent().getData();
}

public void insertBeforeCurrentNode(Object bcNode) //beforeCurrentNode
{
    Node current;
    Node hold;
    boolean done;
    hold = allocateNode();
    hold.setData(bcNode);
    current = getListPtr();
    done = false;
    if (isEmpty())
    {
        setListPtr(hold);
        setCurrent(hold);       
    }

    else if (getCurrent() == getListPtr())
    {
    //  System.out.println("hi" + hold);
        hold.setNext(getCurrent());
        setListPtr(hold);
    }

    else if (!isEmpty() && getCurrent() != getListPtr())
    {
        while (!done && current.getNext() != null)
        {
            //System.out.println("in else if " + hold);
            if (current.getNext() == getCurrent())
            {
                //previous.setNext(hold);
                //System.out.println("hi"+ "yo" + " " + getListPtr());
                hold.setNext(current.getNext());
                current.setNext(hold);
                done = true; 
            }

            //previous = current;
            current = current.getNext();
        }

    }
    //System.out.println("current " + getCurrent());
    //System.out.println("pointer " + getListPtr());

}

public void insertAfterCurrentNode(Object acNode) //afterCurrentNode
{
    Node hold;
    hold = allocateNode();
    hold.setData(acNode);
    if (isEmpty())
    {
        setListPtr(hold);
        setCurrent(hold);
        //System.out.println(hold + " hi");
    }

    else 
    {
        //System.out.println(hold + " hia");
        hold.setNext(getCurrent().getNext());
        getCurrent().setNext(hold);
    }
}

public void insert(Object iNode)
{
    insertAfterCurrentNode(iNode);
}

public Object deleteCurrentNode()
{
    //System.out.println("in delete current");
    Object nData;
    Node previous;

    if (isEmpty()) {throw new ListEmptyException("The list is currently empty! last()");} //if list is empty throw exception

    checkCurrent(); //check if currentNode is null, method throws exception if it is.

    nData = getCurrent().getData();

    if (getCurrent() == getListPtr())
    {
        setListPtr(getCurrent().getNext());
        setCurrent(getCurrent().getNext());
        nodeCount = nodeCount -1;
    }

    else 
    {
        previous = getListPtr();
        while (previous.getNext() != getCurrent())
        {
            previous = previous.getNext();
            //System.out.println("test"+ previous);
        }


        if (getCurrent().getNext() != null)
        {
            previous.setNext(null);
        }

        previous.setNext(getCurrent().getNext());       }

    return nData;
}

public Object deleteFirstNode(boolean toDelete)
{
    if (toDelete)
    {
        setListPtr(null);
    }
    return getListPtr();
}

public Object deleteFirstNode()
{
    Object deleteFirst;
    deleteFirst = deleteFirstNode(true);
    return deleteFirst;
}

public int size()
{
    return this.nodeCount;
}

public String toString()
{
    String nodeString;
    Node sNode;
    sNode = getListPtr();
    //System.out.println(nodeCount);
    nodeString = ("List contains " + nodeCount + " nodes");
    while (sNode != null)
    {
        nodeString = nodeString + " " +sNode.getData();
        sNode = sNode.getNext();
    }   
    return nodeString;
}

private Node allocateNode()
{
    Node newNode;
    newNode = new Node();
    nodeCount = nodeCount + 1;
    return newNode;
}

private void deAllocateNode(Node dNode)
{
    dNode.setData(null);
}

private Node getListPtr()
{
    return this.firstNode;
}

private void setListPtr(Node pNode)
{
     this.firstNode = pNode;
}

private Node getCurrent()
{
    return this.currentNode;
}

private void setCurrent(Node cNode)
{
    this.currentNode = cNode;
}

private void checkCurrent()
{
    if (getCurrent() == null) {throw new InvalidPositionInListException("Current node is null and is set to an invalid position within the list! checkCurrent()");}
}

/**NODE CLASS ----------------------------------------------*/

    private class Node 
    {
        private Node next; //serves as a reference to the next node 
        private Object data;

        public Node()
        {
            this.next = null;
            this.data = null;
        }


        public Object getData()
        {
            return this.data;
        }

        public void setData(Object obj)
        {
            this.data = obj;
        }

        public Node getNext()
        {
            return this.next;
        }

        public void setNext(Node nextNode)
        {
            this.next = nextNode;
        }

        public String toString()
        {
            String nodeString;
            Node sNode;
            sNode = getListPtr();
            //System.out.println(nodeCount);
            nodeString = ("List contains " + nodeCount + " nodes");
            while (sNode != null)
            {
                nodeString = nodeString + " " +sNode.getData();
                sNode = sNode.getNext();
            }   
            return nodeString;
        }
    }


 }
```

[4] should read the same as [2] (List contains 0 nodes.)

Note: Cannot use any more variables/methods/etc that I already have. And I cannot use head nodes.

Comment: You are actually not doing anything here, I don't understand what's your problem.

Comment: You're NOT deleting the node, which should be in "previous"

Comment: copied the wrong version of my program sorry. it's been updated. The method itself is supposed to return the data part of the current node being deleted, but right now I'm just trying to traverse the list so that my previous variable is at the currentNode.

Comment: The problem is that my deleteCurrentNode() method is giving me a null pointer exception, but I don't understand that is. At the beginning of the method I check to see if the currentNode is null, and if so it should throw an exception that I wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class LinkedList 
{
private Node currentNode;
private Node firstNode;
private int nodeCount;


public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  String     data;
  Object     hold;
  LinkedList list;

  data = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  hold = null;
  list = new LinkedList();

  for(int i=0; i< data.length(); i++) { list.insert(new String(new char[] { data.charAt(i) }));  }
  System.out.println("[1] "+list);

  for(int i=0; i< data.length(); i++) { list.deleteCurrentNode(); }
  System.out.println("[2] "+list);

  for(int i=0; i< data.length(); i++)
  {
   list.insertBeforeCurrentNode(new String(new char[] { data.charAt(i) }));
   if(i%2 == 0) { list.first(); } else { list.last(); }
  }

  System.out.println("[3] "+list);

  for(int i=0; i< data.length(); i++) { list.last(); list.deleteCurrentNode(); }
  System.out.println("[4] "+list);


  for(int i=0; i< data.length(); i++) { list.insert(new String(new char[] { data.charAt(i) })); list.last(); }
  System.out.println("[5] "+list);

  while(!list.isEmpty()) { list.deleteFirstNode(); }
  System.out.println("[6] "+list);

  for(int i=0; i< data.length(); i++) { list.insert(new String(new char[] { data.charAt(i) })); list.last(); }
  System.out.println("[7] "+list);

  while(!list.isEmpty()) { list.deleteFirstNode(false); }
  System.out.println("[8] "+list);

  for(int i=0; i< data.length(); i++) { list.insertBeforeCurrentNode(new String(new char[] { data.charAt(i) })); list.first(); }
  System.out.println("[9] "+list);

  list.first();
  list.next();
  list.deleteFirstNode(true);
  list.deleteCurrentNode();
  for(int i=0; i< 5; i++)  { hold = list.getData();  list.next(); }
  for(int i=0; i< 10; i++) { list.next();   }
  list.insertAfterCurrentNode(hold);
  list.first();
  list.next();
  hold = list.getData();
  list.deleteCurrentNode();
  for(int i=0; i<9; i++)  {list.deleteCurrentNode();  list.last(); }
  list.insert(hold);
  list.first();
  list.next();
  list.next();
  list.next();
  list.deleteFirstNode(false);
  hold = list.getData();
  list.deleteCurrentNode();
  list.last();
  list.insertAfterCurrentNode(hold);
  list.deleteFirstNode();
  list.deleteFirstNode();
  hold = list.getData();
  list.deleteFirstNode();
  list.last();
  list.insertBeforeCurrentNode(hold);
  list.first();
  for(int i=0; i<6; i++) { list.next(); }
  hold = list.getData();
  list.deleteCurrentNode();
  list.last();
  list.insertBeforeCurrentNode(hold);
  list.first();
  list.deleteCurrentNode();
  list.deleteCurrentNode();
  hold = list.getData();
  list.deleteCurrentNode();
  for (int i=0; i< 7; i++) { list.next(); }
  list.insertBeforeCurrentNode(hold);
  for (int i=0; i< 4; i++) { list.first(); list.deleteCurrentNode(); }
  System.out.println("\n\n"+list);


 }

public LinkedList()
{
    setListPtr(null);
    setCurrent(null);
    nodeCount = 0;
}

public boolean atEnd()
{
    if (getCurrent() != null)
       {
         return getCurrent().getNext() == null;
       }
       return true;

}

public boolean isEmpty()
{
    return getListPtr() == null;
}

public void first()
{
    setCurrent(getListPtr());
}

public void next()
{
    checkCurrent();
    if (atEnd()) {throw new InvalidPositionInListException("You are at the end of the list. There is no next node. next().");}
    setCurrent(this.currentNode.getNext());
}

public void last()
{
    if (isEmpty()) {throw new ListEmptyException("The list is currently empty! last()");}

    while (!atEnd())
    {
        setCurrent(getCurrent().getNext());
    }

}

public Object getData()
{
    return getCurrent().getData();
}

public void insertBeforeCurrentNode(Object bcNode) //beforeCurrentNode
{
    Node current;
    Node hold;
    boolean done;
    hold = allocateNode();
    hold.setData(bcNode);
    current = getListPtr();
    done = false;
    if (isEmpty())
    {
        setListPtr(hold);
        setCurrent(hold);       
    }

    else if (getCurrent() == getListPtr())
    {
    //  System.out.println("hi" + hold);
        hold.setNext(getCurrent());
        setListPtr(hold);
    }

    else if (!isEmpty() && getCurrent() != getListPtr())
    {
        while (!done && current.getNext() != null)
        {
            //System.out.println("in else if " + hold);
            if (current.getNext() == getCurrent())
            {
                //previous.setNext(hold);
                //System.out.println("hi"+ "yo" + " " + getListPtr());
                hold.setNext(current.getNext());
                current.setNext(hold);
                done = true; 
            }

            //previous = current;
            current = current.getNext();
        }

    }
    //System.out.println("current " + getCurrent());
    //System.out.println("pointer " + getListPtr());

}

public void insertAfterCurrentNode(Object acNode) //afterCurrentNode
{
    Node hold;
    hold = allocateNode();
    hold.setData(acNode);
    if (isEmpty())
    {
        setListPtr(hold);
        setCurrent(hold);
        //System.out.println(hold + " hi");
    }

    else 
    {
        //System.out.println(hold + " hia");
        hold.setNext(getCurrent().getNext());
        getCurrent().setNext(hold);
    }
}

public void insert(Object iNode)
{
    insertAfterCurrentNode(iNode);
}

public Object deleteCurrentNode()
{
    //System.out.println("in delete current");
    Object nData;
    Node previous;

    if (isEmpty()) {throw new ListEmptyException("The list is currently empty! last()");} //if list is empty throw exception

    checkCurrent(); //check if currentNode is null, method throws exception if it is.

    nData = getCurrent().getData();

    if (getCurrent() == getListPtr())
    {
        setListPtr(getCurrent().getNext());
        setCurrent(getCurrent().getNext());
        nodeCount = nodeCount -1;
    }

    else 
    {
        previous = getListPtr();
        //System.out.println(getCurrent());
        //System.out.println(previous + "ptrb ");
        while (previous.getNext() != getCurrent())
        {
            previous = previous.getNext();
            //System.out.println("test"+ previous);
        }

        //System.out.println(previous.getNext() == getCurrent());

        if (previous.getNext() == getCurrent())
        {
            //System.out.println("say hi");
            previous.setNext(getCurrent().getNext());
            deAllocateNode(getCurrent());
            setCurrent(previous);
            nodeCount = nodeCount - 1;
        }

        previous.setNext(getCurrent().getNext());

    }

    return nData;
}

public Object deleteFirstNode(boolean toDelete)
{
    if (toDelete)
    {
        setCurrent(getListPtr().getNext());
    }
    deAllocateNode(getListPtr());
    setListPtr(getListPtr().getNext());

    nodeCount = nodeCount - 1;
    return getListPtr();
}

public Object deleteFirstNode()
{
    Object deleteFirst;
    deleteFirst = deleteFirstNode(true);
    //System.out.println("called");
    return deleteFirst;
}

public int size()
{
    return this.nodeCount;
}

public String toString()
{
    String nodeString;
    Node sNode;
    sNode = getListPtr();
    //System.out.println(nodeCount);
    nodeString = ("List contains " + nodeCount + " nodes");
    while (sNode != null)
    {
        nodeString = nodeString + " " +sNode.getData();
        sNode = sNode.getNext();
    }   
    return nodeString;
}

private Node allocateNode()
{
    Node newNode;
    newNode = new Node();
    nodeCount = nodeCount + 1;
    return newNode;
}

private void deAllocateNode(Node dNode)
{
    dNode.setData(null);
}

private Node getListPtr()
{
    return this.firstNode;
}

private void setListPtr(Node pNode)
{
     this.firstNode = pNode;
}

private Node getCurrent()
{
    return this.currentNode;
}

private void setCurrent(Node cNode)
{
    this.currentNode = cNode;
}

private void checkCurrent()
{
    if (getCurrent() == null) {throw new InvalidPositionInListException("Current node is null and is set to an invalid position within the list! checkCurrent()");}
}

/**NODE CLASS ----------------------------------------------*/

    private class Node 
    {
        private Node next; //serves as a reference to the next node 
        private Object data;

        public Node()
        {
            this.next = null;
            this.data = null;
        }


        public Object getData()
        {
            return this.data;
        }

        public void setData(Object obj)
        {
            this.data = obj;
        }

        public Node getNext()
        {
            return this.next;
        }

        public void setNext(Node nextNode)
        {
            this.next = nextNode;
        }

        public String toString()
        {
            String nodeString;
            Node sNode;
            sNode = getListPtr();
            //System.out.println(nodeCount);
            nodeString = ("List contains " + nodeCount + " nodes");
            while (sNode != null)
            {
                nodeString = nodeString + " " +sNode.getData();
                sNode = sNode.getNext();
            }   
            return nodeString;
        }
    }


  }
```

Thanks so much everyone for your contributions. They've helped me solve my problem (although somewhat obscurely.)

I'm answering my own question so that if anyone else happens to have a similar problem, they can use it as a tool of reference.

Once again, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

if you have a Node class, representing one node of the list like:

```
public class Node{
public Object value;
public Node next;

public Node(){

}

public Node(Object p){
    value= p;
}

public String toString(){
    return "" + this.value.toString();
}
}
```

Than you in your List implementation (let's say MyList) you will have (methods only for removing):

```
public class MyList{
  private Node head;

public Object removeFirst(){
    if(head == null){
        return null;
    }

    Object o= head.value;
    head= head.next;
    return o;
}

    // remove by index
public Object remove(int i){
    int n= this.size();
    if(i<0 || i>=n){
        return null;
    }

    if(i==0){
        return this.removeFirst();
    }

    int k=0;
    Node t= head;

    while(k < i-1){
        t= t.next;
        k= k+1;
    }

    Object o= t.next.value;
    t.next= t.next.next;

    return o;
}

    //remove by object
    public boolean remove(Object o){
    int k= this.indexOf(o);
    if(k<0){
        return false;
    }   
    this.remove(k);

    return true;
}

    //not necessary, but you may study the logic
    public Object removeLast(){
    Object o= null;
    if(head!=null){
        if(head.next==null){
            o= head.value;
            head= null;
        }else{
            Node t= head.next;
            while(t.next.next != null){
                t= t.next;
            }
            o= t.next.value;
            t.next= null;
        }
    }
    return o;
}
 }
```

Edit: you have some problems when your array is only containing 1 element.

For example in your last() method ->

```
    while (!atEnd()) {
        setCurrent(getCurrent().getNext());
    }
```

Comment: For my implementation I must have two different nodes, the currentNode and the firstNode. For the method I'm having trouble with, I have to locate the currentNode in the list and delete it but I can't get my method to work correctly.

Comment: I have posted this code, to imply that, deleteCurrent() should be equal to == getIndexOfCurrnet() - > deleteByIndex(indexOfcurrent)

Comment: I can't find the currentNode (or index of it) by iterating through my program.

In my program I set my local node "previous" to the beginning of the list. Then, while previous.next is not equal to the currentNode I iterate through (previous = previous.next.) 

at the end of my while statement a print statement comparing previous and getCurrent() should show true, but it doesn't, and that's where my problem lies.

Comment: In your tests you have deleteCurrentNode() on two places: after System.out.println("[1] " + test); and System.out.println("[3] " + test); I have commented out the other tests, and I executed the code, it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider guarding against `null` in your code. It's best not to make assumptions.

For instance,

```
public boolean atEnd()
{
    return getCurrent().getNext() == null;

}
```

might be better written as

```
public boolean atEnd()
{
   if (getCurrent() != null)
   {
     return getCurrent().getNext() == null;
   }
   return true;
}
```

This isn't necessarily the best way to do it; you might want to throw a `NoCurrentNodeException` or something. It depends on the semantics you're looking for.

Either way, you won't get buried in `NullPointerExceptions`.